# What is the main purpose of audit-argument-checks?

Tags: meteor

For example,

```
findByType: function(type) {
   check(type, String);
   var role;
   if(type === 'user') {
       role = 'user'
   } else if(type === 'admin') {
       role = 'admin'
   }
   Accounts.find({role: role})
}
```

in this case, `check(type, String);` is not necessary?

so if I have my own check codes, there is no need to use audit-argument-checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`audit-argument-checks` requires all your Meteor methods to actually `check` each of their arguments, if they don't, an error message will be logged on the server and presented to the client as a "500 Internal server error".

This package helps you making sure all your methods implement basic security checking, but it does not check your arguments for you (it can't guess the intended types of your arguments), so you still need to call `check` unless you want this package to throw errors.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks

Answer (score 0):

You could also improve your check by doing the following (unless you want to be searching for Accounts.find({role: null}) when the type is neither 'admin' nor 'user'):

```
findByType: function(type) {
  check(type, Match.Where((type)=>{
    check(type, String);
    return type=="user" || type=="admin";
  }));

  Accounts.find({role: type});
}
```

I know it's been a while this question has been asked but I found it while searching for something else and thought I could suggest a better form.